# Let $\left( a_{n}\right) _{n}$ be a Cauchy sequence such that $\left\{ a_{n}:n\in \mathbb{N} \right\}$ is finite.

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

Let $\left( a_{n}\right) _{n}$ be a Cauchy sequence such that $\left\{ a_{n}:n\in \mathbb{N} \right\}$ is finite. Show that $\left( a_{n}\right) _{n}$ is constant.

Comment: I'm not sure of that fact. Let's take $a_{1}=1,a_{n}=0\,\forall\,n\geq 2$. It is not a constant sequence, but it is a Cauchy-sequence admitting a finite number of values.
$(a_{n})_{n}$ is probably constant starting from some $n$

Comment: @MoebiusCorzer, I believe the question should be "Show that $\{a_n\}_n$ is *eventually* constant."

Comment: @MarcusM Yes, I realized that just when you were writing it.

Comment: @MarcusM Right: not *constant* (easy counterexamples), but *eventually* constant. @ OP: does that help?

Comment: @N.Raki this is clearly a homework question, so you should say what you've tried. This isn't Wolfram.

Comment: I showed that let $\left( a_{n}\right) _{n}$ where $\left( a_{n}\right) _{n}=a$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ converges to $a$. Yet, could'nt show this question.

Comment: Why eventually constant?

Comment: @MarcusM If this not eventually, wtf (what if)?

Comment: @Almentoe Why eventually constant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us denote $A=\{|a_n-a_k|:n,k\in \mathbb{N}\}\setminus\{0\}$. Since $\{a_n:n\in \mathbb{N}\} $ is finite $A$ is finite as well which follows there is a minimum in $A$. Denote $m=min\{a\in A\}$. Note that $m>0$ because $0\not \in A$. $\{a_n\}$ is cauchy which implies that there exists $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\forall n>n_0$ $0\leq|a_{n+1}-a_n|<m$. If  $0<|a_{n+1}-a_n|<m$ it's a contradiction to the definition of $m$. So we have $\forall n>n_0$ $a_n=a_{n_0}$.

Answer (score 0):

We assume the space is complete e.g. $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$

if $\left\{ a_{n}:n\in \mathbb{N} \right\}^2$ is finite then so is $\left\{ |a_{n} - a_{m}|:n,m\in \mathbb{N} \right\}$

hence $\left\{ a_{n}:n\in \mathbb{N} \right\}$ has a minimum separation $\epsilon$

$\left\{ a_{n}:n\in \mathbb{N} \right\}$ is Cauchy and so eventually a tail will all be within $\epsilon/2$ of each other, so this tail is constant $\square$